# Apache Freemarker - Loop output of split function across multiple lines

Tags: freemarker

How would I use the split function in Freemarker to output the split string across multiple lines?

Example, the input of the template will be "1.2.3.4" which is easy enough to split by a period.

```
<#list "1.2.3.4"?split(".") as x>
${x}
<#/list>
```

The x variable would output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Which I now need to apply to 4 different locations. Example, my template has 4 spots that I need the split input to be applied to. Ideally, I'd want it to look like this:

```
<ParameterA>1</ParameterA>
<ParameterB>2</ParameterB>
<ParameterC>3</ParameterC>
<ParameterD>4</ParameterD>
```

I've tried doing it like this:

```
<#list "1.2.3.4"?split(".") as x>
    <ParameterA>${x[0]}</ParameterA>
    <ParameterB>${x[1]}</ParameterB>
    <ParameterC>${x[2]}</ParameterC>
    <ParameterD>${x[3]}</ParameterD>
<#/list>
```

but Freemarker throws this when I test it:

```
String index out of range: The index was 1 (0-based), but the length of the string is only 1.
```

Obviously I'm missing something. Is there a way to select a specific value from the output of the split function? And if not, what's the best way to loop through and apply the output of the split to the respective parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```
<#assign x = "1.2.3.4"?split(".")>

<ParameterA>${x[0]}</ParameterA>
<ParameterB>${x[1]}</ParameterB>
<ParameterC>${x[2]}</ParameterC>
<ParameterD>${x[3]}</ParameterD>
```